# c++-cli DLLs load-time dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

When building a c++-cli in Visual Studio 2010 with /clr /md options in Release mode, the resulting assembly is dependent on these when I run the Dependency Walker on the build release assembly.

c:\windows\system32\MSVCR100.DLL
c:\windows\system32\MSVCP100.DLL
c:\windows\system32\MSVCP100D.DLL
c:\windows\system32\MSVCR100D.DLL

Why are MSVCP100D.DLL & MSVCR100D.DLL there? I thought they are supposed to be there only for Debug build mode. How do I remove the dependency on the debug dlls MSVCP100D.DLL & MSVCR100D.DLL?

Comment: Looks like the mscoree.lib is only built with the debug libraries. Would be interesting to know if this is not true and how to get the release version of this library.

Comment: Recompile *all* of the .obj and .libs you link with release mode settings.  You can diagnose it with the linker's /VERBOSE option.

Comment: Never mind. It turned out I was using Debug libraries for OpenCV in the release mode.